# Entity Framework 6.0 and Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

Tags: entity-framework-6

We are moving our on-prem database to Azure.  Our applications use Entity Framework 6. Everything works fine using System.Data.SqlClient using the authentication Microsoft Active Directory Password once we install the ADALSQL.dll. When you go to the site referenced in the exception message when this dll is not installed the site responds with a 404.

> Encountered an unexpected error.
> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Unable to load adalsql.dll (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword). Error code: 0x2. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=513072

A couple of weeks ago it was available.

With ADALSQL being deprecated we are trying to get the application to use `Microsoft.Data.SQLClient`. I've tried the following:

- Added Nuget package `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` to the project
- Added the following to the `app.config` file

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider" 
             invariant="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" 
             description="Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider for SQL Server" 
             type="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

- Updated the providers section in the `EntityFramework` section of the `app.config` file to the following

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
        <!--<provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />-->
        <provider invariantName="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient"  
                  type="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

- Updated the connection string to reference the provider `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`

```
<add name="B2BEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.B2B.csdl|res://*/Models.B2B.ssdl|res://*/Models.B2B.msl;provider=Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=
```

Upon running the application the following exception is thrown:

> The 'Instance' member of the Entity Framework provider type 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5' did not return an object that inherits from 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices'. Entity Framework providers must inherit from this class and the 'Instance' member must return the singleton instance of the provider. This may be because the provider does not support Entity Framework 6 or later; see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

Any guidance on how to get this working would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I have published https://www.nuget.org/packages/ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServer that enables exactly this.

Comment: [Can you please expand on your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168712/what-is-stack-overflows-take-on-link-only-answers), such as with an overview of how to use your library and what any drawbacks are?

Comment: @dai it is all explained in extensive details  in the link.